# Question regarding German D-Visa

Tags: germany, working-visas

I have a valid German D-Visa with a validity of 6months and a valid Job Contract for `Company A` as `XYZ` for an unlimited period.

The Zusatblatt (Supplementary Sheet) mentions I can only work for `Company A` as `XYZ`.

I am still in my home country (Not Germany), and I would like to know if I get another offer from `Company B` as `ABC` can I still travel with the original D-Visa and work for `Company B` or would I have to re-apply for a new D-Visa?

Comment: Related question: https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/a/14600/13223

Answer (score 1):

You need a permission for work at Company B on the first working day there. IMHO (and I'm not a lawyer), you can either reapply for new visa, or enter with current visa and apply for residence permit. But you will only be able to start working at Company B when this new visa or residence permit is issued.

Comment: What if `Company A` is shut down before I even land in Germany? Can I still travel with D-Visa issued for `Company A` and apply for a Residence Permit? Do I need any documentation from `Company A` to apply for a residence permit?

Comment: Well, I guess nobody can give you a guarantee about such situations. However, if, let's say a person enters country with a visa with work permit for one company, and next day gets an offer from another - in my eyes nothing can stop him/her from applying for a residence permit with purpose of work at that another company. The immigration office will probably restart checking the conditions for one to work at that company from scratch. Here no guarantees can be given as well. If the conditions are similar, the chance of getting it is very high, but I cannot predict future and I'm not a lawyer.

Comment: One more important point is that one might need to cancel the contract from Company A if you have signed it. Otherwise, very theoretically they might do some actions against him/her not following the contract (e.g., not starting working). I do not mean any claims to consulate or immigration office, I mean things like economic losses, need to search for other candidates, etc. In practice, even if one does not come to work after signing contract, the chance that any legal actions will follow is very low. However, it is much better to clarify everything in a good manner with both companies.

Comment: Finally, one will probably have a trial period in Company A. If one signs a contract with Company B during this trial period, gets a residence permit valid from some date in future, let's say 3 weeks later and then cancels the contract with Company A 2 weeks in advance, it might be quite clear legally. So there are a lot of options. If unsure, consult a proper lawyer, because of Covid, most of them work remotely now.

Comment: Thank you, your inputs have been very helpful!